# Phonegap ios image upload as formdata not working,

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

In my Phonegap application ios image upload is not working for some time, don't know the exact reason for uploading,
Here I have upload the image as formdata,
ex code - 
To get the picture from photos,

```
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="attachment" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)"/>
<button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b" ng-click="post()"> Upload file</button>
```

JS Coding-
//CALLS UPLOAD FILE METHOD

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files)
{
   var fd = new FormData();
   //Take the first selected file
   fd.append("attachment", files[0]);
   $localStorage.fd = fd;
};

$scope.post=function()
 {
    var fd=$localStorage.fd;
    $http.post(httpurl, fd,
       {
         headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
         transformRequest: angular.identity
        })
    .success(function (res) {
    alert("Image upload successfully");
    })
    .error(function(res){
    alert("Image not uploaded");
})
```

Now the issue is, image is uploading sometime and not know the actual issue. I have tried to post the same image upload but it's reflects same issue.
Please share your feedback to fix my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: Append doesn't work in Safari iOS.

I've had a similar issue puzzle me for days. 
Then I discovered that some FormData functions are not compatible in many browsers, including Safari iOS.

See compatibility list here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

I got around the issue by having my fields in a form, and passing the entire form as: new FormData(form).

Comment: Thank you. took me days - I thought it was a weird bug with aurelia, I never got an error or anything helpful.